# Use of {% %} in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jinja2

What is the use of `{%  %}` in JavaScript? For example, in code:

```
{% for head in fact_headers %}
```

Is that a comment or notation of a block?

Comment: Java or JavaScript? That I guess django

Comment: @Durga in edit assumed that it's JavaScript as it is in caption and the tag :)

Comment: Looks like a Django template tag.

Comment: maybe something like handlebars?

Comment: `{%%}` is not standard JavaScript and is used in various template engines, the question is too broad to answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

template engine notation, used by libraries like twig in symfony or blade in laravel, 
you can find details in this [link](http://www.mitchellbosecke.com/pebble/documentation/guide/basic-usage#control-structure)

Comment: Not an answer..